Are Pause and Ctrl+S different in Windows Terminal & Console Host?
I know that Windows terminal applications have changed over time when looking at how they allow users to make the terminal pause accepting output.
Ctrl+S (XOFF) and Ctrl+Q (XON) used to work, then didn't work, and now in Windows Terminal Ctrl+S has reappeared, but instead of Ctrl+Q you can resume with any key.
The Pause key seems to have the same effect, but according to some sources it shouldn't work, and other sources say there's a difference (where Ctrl+S stops accepting output, Pause supposedly actually suspends the process).
I've found it difficult to find reliable documentation, and from my own experience, Pause and Ctrl+S seem to have the same effect on console applications. They will continue to run for a small amount of time and then drop to 0% CPU, resuming when another key is pressed, which usually results in a small amount of output immediately appearing, and the console application resuming its normal function.
Does anyone know with some certainty:

whether Pause and Ctrl+S are the same or different in Windows Terminal? (in Windows 11)
whether Pause in Windows Terminal is the same as Pause in Windows Console Host? (it does not support Ctrl+S in current Windows versions, not by default anyway)
whether both or either actually do something to the running process, or whether it's just a matter of writing to standard out becoming blocking due to the terminal window no longer accepting the output?


Windows Terminal Ctrl+S and Pause do the same thing and block stdout. Console does not support Ctrl+S (only Pause).
In general, for terminals, certain keys have an ASCII correspondence:

Esc = Ctrl-[
Tab = Ctrl-I
Bksp = Ctrl-? (DEL)
Enter = Ctrl-M

There are no keyboards with physical keys for XON/XOFF (software flow control) so Ctrl-S / Ctrl-Q are used instead.
Canonically, Scroll Lock (or Hold on VT keyboards) should just stop writing to the screen. However, the implementation of a software terminal emulator may vary.
To quote from the VT520 manual: "While in "local", host communications are put on "hold": All data received is buffered. If necessary, an XOFF is sent (or DTR is deasserted) to prevent buffer overflow. This buffered data is directed to the display when On-line mode is reentered."
So the answer is, canonically: Scroll Lock might send a Ctrl-S only if SW Flow Control is enabled, otherwise Scroll Lock might set DTR off (Data Terminal not Ready - effectively disconnecting). Might = only on buffer overflow. On modern systems there might be enough screen buffer available for that to never happen.
The mis-use of Pause for that is due to the more vague naming. The equivalent is documented in the VT520 manual in Section C. Pause unmodified does a Disconnect, Ctrl+Pause sends a Break.


I think your answer provides very good historic context for what I'm asking about, and perhaps I'm just missing it, but I feel it doesn't answer the the (admittedly three-part) question regarding the implementations in WIndows Terminal and Windows Console Host, would you mind addressing those directly in your answer, possibly based on what you already shared? I'm sorry to say I fail to answer those three questions based on the information you provided alone.

I added the explanation explicitly on the first row.

I followed up and tried to dig a bit deeper to try and answer my own question based on what I learnt about the terminal situation on Windows.
A few things I wasn't aware of before:

Windows Terminal presents a new and integrated front-end for terminal interaction on Windows, and replaces Console Host in the sense of being a GUI for terminal interaction. However, it doesn't fully replace Console Host - conhost.exe remains an important part of terminal interaction, even when using Windows Terminal. I found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/definitions particularly useful.
ConPTY is a thing. I know, I should have known, but I didn't. This is an excellent article that's essential reading for anyone asking the same questions I did, even though it doesn't exactly address the question directly: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/
Sending a single character with ASCII code 19 (XOFF) to Windows Terminal, while running a console application that handles raw input and output directly and configuring Windows Terminal to launch the application as a profile, shows that Windows Terminal maps XOFF onto Ctrl+S, because that is what ends up in the application.

I ended up writing a very simple Rust application that just writes output periodically and logs timestamps of itself doing so to file. This show execution halting whenever you press Pause or Ctrl+S from Windows Terminal as output can no longer be written and the application is blocked (as user @DorianB indicates).
Another simple Rust application that instead uses crossterm (which allows configuring the Windows Console API to pass through all raw input) runs without pausing, but does show that passing an ASCII character #19 to the terminal (using AutoHotKey) results in the raw input application receiving Ctrl+S.
To then answer my own questions:

Are Pause and Ctrl+S the same or different in Windows Terminal? (in Windows 11); They have the same effect on applications that don't flag the Windows Console API to pass through raw input, and both cause Windows Terminal to suspend output from a console application, blocking it.
Pause in Windows Terminal is the same as Pause in Windows Console Host?; Both cause the output to be immediately suspended, blocking an application trying to write.
Do they actually do something to the running process, or is it just a matter of writing to standard out becoming blocking due to the terminal window no longer accepting the output?; The latter, writing to standard out becomes blocking. However, depending on the platform the application is written on, it's possible that the application itself buffers output for some time and it may only start blocking once those buffers fill up.

Note that I will accept @DorianB.'s  answer since they essentially answered it - but I felt some more explanation may be needed. They do provide some interesting background. I certainly needed, because their answer (although technically correct) did not suffice to help understand what was going on.
